# Laravel - Configurar storage en un directorio distinto donde está el proyecto

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-7

Tengo un proyecto situado en esta ruta  **/var/www/html/backend/api_cars**

Y tengo configurado un storage para colgar ciertos archivos en la carpeta "public", pero ahora necesitaría subir una serie de ficheros (para ello uso dropzone js) pero con la particularidad que al subirse deben copiarse a un directorio que no esta dentro del proyecto,

Su ruta esta **/var/www/html/images/catalog/cars**

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacerlo con laravel, he probado a configurar un "storage" de tipo "carpeta" pero me da error.

En el archivo config/filesystems.php he creado esto

```
        'public' => [
        'driver' => 'images-cars',
        'root' => storage_path('/var/www/html/images/catalog/cars'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/catalog-cars',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Se me había ocurrido crear un "Symbolic link" dentro de una carpeta del proyecto a la otra carpeta, pero no se si funcionaria.

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: utilizas para devolver imagenes el facade Storage?

Comment: Si @Dohko19 , lo uso

Comment: entonces laravel espera obttener imagenes de esta ruta 'storage/app//var/www/html/images/catalog/cars', y creo que lo que tienes alli es una carpeta externa al proyecto, cierto?